# Javascript: Automatically clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, onclick

I'm learning how to write a chrome extension, and I'm fairly new to javascript.

Here's some html:

```
<div class="button data" style="">
   <a class="button1 whiteColor" href="http://link1.com">VIEW This</a>
   <a class="button2 redColor" href="http://link2.com">VIEW That</a>
</div>
```

What I want to do is open link2.com by automatically clicking button2 using javascript.

I'm using the following, but it's not working :/

```
document.getElementByClassName("button2 redColor").click();
```

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("button2 redColor")[0].click();`

Comment: Thank you LightStyle, I just wasn't sure how to grab the a button already inside another class!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("button2 redColor")[0].click();
```

You need select index, because getElementsByClassName return the array

Comment: An answer - in my opinion - is not necessary in this case. Anyway, your solution won't work because it is `getElements` and not `getElement`. Pay attention to the typos(even of the OP)!

Comment: @Zenith `.click()` exists even for DOM elements, it's not a jQuery function(in this case)

Comment: @NiccolòCampolungo getElements is correct. it returns an array of elements, in case you need to retrieve all elements of the same class